# Changing Facebook page category from Product/Services to App page

Tags: facebook

I have a Facebook page that is of the category Product/Services. I want to get data (about post/comments) from my page. For this, I have to change my page category to App page - so that I can link my app to the page.

Does changing the category from Product/Services to App page, affect my page in any way?

Or - Is there a way to connect my app to the page without changing the page category to app page?

Could not find this in Facebook documentation.

**Note -** Facebook has 2 dropdowns for category, in the edit page info -

My page is  - dropdown 1 - Brand and Products

dropdown 2 - Product/Services

I will have to change it to dropdown 1 - Brand and Products

dropdown 2 - App page

Only then we can connect my app to the page and get data from it.
Or is there any other way to get data without changing the dropdown 2?

Answer (score -2):

I believe ypu can actually go to settings and thwn go to my accoynts and click manage my accoubts you delete it or you just sync it allinto one email so you can see allof themat one time and you dont miss no inxomng mail.